# Transition / Animation Not Working in Angular 1.3?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `span` element that I want to fade in when a button is clicked.  I've set properties related to `ng-enter` and `ng-enter-active` as follows:

```
span{
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
span.ng-enter{
    transition: 0.75s;
    opacity: 0;
}
span.ng-enter-active{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But the fade in effect is not present.  When I look at the DOM, it doesn't look like the transition classes are ever attached to the element.

What's wrong here?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjc2sbxo/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) (see "Animation" section), `ngHide` utilizes the `ng-hide` class for animations. Use this class in css instead of `ng-enter`.

So you want to perform animation only for fade in, not fade out. On fade in element have extra class: `ng-hide-remove`. Add animation for it:

```
/* initial state before animation */
span.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
/* state after animation */
span.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjc2sbxo/3/)

Comment: I noticed this will fade in and fade out the element when it shows / hides, respectively.  I only want the fade in, not the fade out - the element should disappear immediately when the linked JS variable is set to `false`.

Comment: Updated my answer for a little. Hope it helps

Comment: Any way to get the same effects using `ng-hide` instead of `ng-if`?

Comment: Updated again. Now with ng-hide

Answer (score 1):

`.ng-enter` is for animating ng-repeat and ng-if.

For ng-hide use `.ng-hide`.

```
span{
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity:1;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
span.ng-hide{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I noticed this will fade in and fade out the element when it shows / hides, respectively.  I only want the fade in, not the fade out - the element should disappear immediately when the linked JS variable is set to `false`.